# Resolve ambigous operator overloading

Tags: c++

I have implemented the following class which wraps a shared pointer.

```
class Wrapper
{
  private:
    std::shared_ptr<const MyClass> mPointer;

  public:
    Wrapper(MyClass* myClass);

    operator bool(void) const;

    const MyClass* operator*(void) const;

    const MyClass* operator->(void) const;

    Wrapper operator!(void) const;    

    Wrapper operator||(Wrapper rhs) const;

    Wrapper operator&&(Wrapper rhs) const;
};
```

An object of the class Wrapper itself should behave like a boolean to be able to write:

```
Wrapper Wrapper_A = Wrapper(new MyClass(true));
Wrapper Wrapper_B = Wrapper(new MyClass(false));

if(Wrapper_A && Wrapper_B) {}
```

Now, consider the following function:

```
void WrapperHandler::add(Wrapper wrapper);
```

If this function is used the following way:

```
add(Wrapper_A);
```

or

```
add(!Wrapper_A);
```

no problem occurs.

But when I write

```
add(Wrapper_A || Wrapper_B);
```

the following compile error occurs (VS 2010):

```
Error   1   error C2664: 'WrapperHandler::add' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'bool' to 'Wrapper'
```

If I overload the operator|| in the following way (to hide the built-in operator):

```
Wrapper operator||(const Wrapper& rhs) const;
```

the error occurs nevertheless.

The following lines work properly:

```
bool test = Wrapper_A || Wrapper_B;
```

Why is the result of operator|| always cast to bool?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Firstly, you should extract a minimal example, as per posting guidelines. Then, consider using non-member operators, at least for the binary operators.

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong question.

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 does not support C11 features. I am surprised you were able to use `shared_ptr` at all.

Comment: What is `new MyClass(true)` supposed to mean? What's myClass?

Comment: The error message tells you that `||` is returning a `bool` - that can only be because you're doing a logical-or of two `operator bool) const` results, so make that operator `explicit` and your problem should go away.

Comment: Also, FWIW [I couldn't duplicate](http://ideone.com/XR7Y0O).

Comment: @RSahu VS 2010 supports *quite a lot* of C++11 features, actually. Not all of them, by far, but a significant subset.

Answer (score 4):

> Why is the result of operator `||` always cast to bool?

It isn't, as per the specification (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators):

> Other than the restrictions above, the language puts no other constraints on what the overloaded operators do, or on the return type

This is a case of operator precedence not being what you might expect.

You have this overridden operator:

```
operator bool(void) const;
```

This means that, when possible, the compiler will try to convert your object to a `bool`. When the compiler encounters this:

```
add(Wrapper_A || Wrapper_B);
```

It is converting both `Wrapper_A` and `Wrapper_B` to a `bool` and *then* running the `||` operator on the result of that conversion.

To resolve the issue, ensure that the `bool` operator is marked as `explicit`, which will stop this conversion from happening automatically.

```
explicit operator bool(void) const;
```

Comment: The explicit keyword would probably do it, but unfortunately explicit operators are not supported in VS2010.